# How do I detect if a browser distinguishes visited links?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, browser-detection

How do I display a message to visitors to my website if their web browser does not distinguish links they have already visited?

Visitors to my [website](http://giveawaylisting.com) like to have links they have already visited distinguished from links they have not, typically by displaying them in a different color.  Most web browsers handle this for them automatically.  Historically, Internet Explorer has been the exception, but since 11/30/16 I have been getting complaints from users of Safari on iPads and iPhones.  I currently use JavaScript to detect Internet Explorer and tell its users to switch to Chrome or Firefox if they want their visited links distinguished.  I was going to do the same for Safari 10, but answers on here about how to detect Safari 10 via JavaScript say things like "You shouldn't do browser detection anymore. You should use feature detection."  Makes sense to me, so how do I detect if a browser distinguishes visited links?

Comment: You don't. We used to allow different styling for that, but as it turns out that's a *great* way to allow 3rd party scripts to see which sites you've visited by just generating a thousand `<a href="...">` elements and then checking whether the CSS styling for them match the "visited" styling. So that was incredibly bad and virtually all browsers stopped treating "visited" as a thing you can check for.

Answer (score 0):

Links show up as `:visited` if they are in the browser's history.  So you are really looking to see if `:visited` is implemented in the browser.  Without doing [feature detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Feature_detection), you can just look here: http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Avisited to find out that what you're looking for is widely implemented.

So why are your users not always getting `:visited` links?  Could be any number of reasons around using private sessions, not saving history, etc.